Can't bind to 'vgMedia' since it isn't a known property of 'video'
i was tring to use VgCoreModule to implement the video function in angular 15. it pops out this error, anyone ideas?
video.module.ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { VideoComponent } from "./video.component";

import { VgApiService, VgCoreModule } from "@videogular/ngx-videogular/core";
import { VgControlsModule } from "@videogular/ngx-videogular/controls";
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from "@videogular/ngx-videogular/overlay-play";
import { VgBufferingModule } from "@videogular/ngx-videogular/buffering";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: VideoComponent,
  },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/" },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [VideoComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    VgCoreModule,
    VgControlsModule,
    VgOverlayPlayModule,
    VgBufferingModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
})
export class VideoModule {}


video.component.html
<div style="width: 800px;">
    <h2>VIDEO PLAYER</h2>
    <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
        <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
        <vg-buffering vgFor="singleVideo"></vg-buffering>
        <vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
            <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
        </vg-scrub-bar>
        <vg-controls>
            <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
            <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
            <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
        
        
        </vg-controls>
        <video #media
                [vgMedia]="$any(media)"
                id="singleVideo"
                preload="auto"
                src="../../../../assets/videos/video.mp4"
                crossorigin>
        </video>
    </vg-player>
</div>

can you tell me how to solve this. why It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!
